# how to convert comma separated string to list of strings in java?

Tags: java

Is there any built-in method in Java which allows us to convert a string into an list of strings. For eg:

```
"1,2,3,4" to "1","2","3","4"
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Sure , what you have tried ?

Comment: This question AGAIN !?

Comment: All answers that show a **full** solution, don't get my +1. OP doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding and we shouldn't encourage this.

Comment: If you write your question in Google, result no. 7 ... http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CommaSeparatedToArray.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, using the `split` method

```
String a = "1,2,3,4";
String[] aa = a.split(",");
```

Into a list:

```
List<String> aaa = Arrays.asList(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `String[]` by split `"1,2,3,4"` by `,`. Then convert that in to `List` by `Arrays.asList()`

```
    String str="1,2,3,4";
    String[] arr=str.split(",");
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro. But output is [1, 2, 3, 4]. I am looking for something like this: "1","2","3","4".

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "1,2,3,4";
String[] tokens = s.split(",");
List<String> tokenlist=Arrays.asList(tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method on String.

```
String str = "1,2,3,4";
String[] listStr = str.split(",");
```